# Resource entry ic_launcher already defined

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

can any body plz help he with this issue i want to use this library on my android studio project

```
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider
```

put when i put it in my gradle file it shows these errors

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources]
Information:res\drawable-mdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher is already defined.
Information:res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png:0: Originally defined here.
Information:res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher is already defined.
Information:res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png:0: Originally defined here.
Information:res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher is already defined.
Information:res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png:0: Originally defined here.
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Razi\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Razi\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\Razi\AndroidStudioProjects\AllahNames\app\build\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Razi\AndroidStudioProjects\AllahNames\app\build\res\all\debug -A C:\Users\Razi\AndroidStudioProjects\AllahNames\app\build\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Razi\AndroidStudioProjects\AllahNames\app\build\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Razi\AndroidStudioProjects\AllahNames\app\build\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.ua.allahnames.app --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Razi\AndroidStudioProjects\AllahNames\app\build\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    res\drawable-mdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher is already defined.
    res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png:0: Originally defined here.
    res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher is already defined.
    res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png:0: Originally defined here.
    res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher is already defined.
    res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png:0: Originally defined here.
```

ic_launcher already defined!
What could be the error?
I have tried to change build tools to 19.1.0 but I don't think it's an issue?

here is my build.gradle code

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Eh, don't you need to download the entire project tree from [https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider), including its resource files?

Comment: im not downloading it i have put a line of code in build.gradle see the updated question above

Comment: All you're doing is including the relevant JAR in the build script. What about the resource files? That's why you're getting the error. You need to download the project somewhere, then include the entire project into your project. Without the resource files, Gradle will complain.

Comment: okayyy can u plz tell me how to do that... downloaded folder has a demo and lib folders shall i include both or the library only... i would appriciate if u ans this with code example

Comment: I can't see from your post what IDE you are using. But for Eclipse, I would do File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace -> Then, when prompted, browse to the directory of AndroidImageSlider and select it. I'm not familiar with Android Studio (AS) so, if you use it, you may need to search for similar answer for AS. Sorry.

Comment: well i mentioned android studio above and we dont need to import libraries in studio like we do in eclipse...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, had too many SO screens open. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm the author of [this library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider). I'm so sorry for making you into this trouble.

There is a solution you can have a try:

rename the `ic_launcher` (in your project `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-xhdpi`, `res/drawable-xxhdpi` ) .

This issue occurs just when there are two files have same name.

Comment: I'v released a new version which solved this issue. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/issues/8

Comment: I released [v1.0.3](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/releases) to fix this problem.

Comment: yea i fixed it the same day by renaming the ic_launcher files but i was wondering how i will put my own ic_launcher but thanks now i can do it with this fix... thank you for the reply!

Comment: @WasifKhalil if you ever encounter something like this again, you can rename your ic_launcher.png files in their respective folders and then change the referenced image from ic_launcher to the new name in your manifest. I belive the author is pushing a fix soon for this library though.

Answer (score 0):

You should clean and re-build your project. To do so, you need to invalidate and then restart Android Studio.

Check below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe files are locked with the emulator, restart the emulator & IDE.